# Youngest Student Information getting error in C++ using Class

Tags: c++

I have created a class called Student and my task is to take the input Name, ID, Age, Gender, Score of 20 students and print the information of the youngest student as output and print the information of the highest numbered student and how many in the class. The girl has her number printed.

My code is working properly only if I add `10, 20, 30`  two or one-digit integer value to the age input. But if I give `1900, 2000` digits like this, then even if all the programs in my program work properly, the information of the youngest student always looks wrong.

My code is given below.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Student {
public:
    string name, gender;
    int id, birthday, score;

    void getName()
    {
        getline(cin, name);
    }
    void getId()
    {
        cin >> id;
    }
    void getBirthDate()
    {
        cin >> birthday;
    }
    void getGender()
    {
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, gender);
    }
    void getScore()
    {
        cin >> score;
    }
};

int main()

{

    Student st[20];
    Student maximum;
    Student young;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << "Student " << i + 1 << endl
             << endl;

        cout << "Enter Name : ";
        st[i].getName();

        cout << "Enter Id : ";
        st[i].getId();

        cout << "Enter Birthday(e.g. 20) : ";
        st[i].getBirthDate();

        cout << "Enter Gender : ";
        st[i].getGender();

        cout << "Enter Score : ";
        st[i].getScore();

        cout << endl
             << endl;
        cin.ignore();
    }

    int minAge = 100;
    int maxScore = -1;
    int femaleCount = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << endl
             << endl;

        if (st[i].gender == "F" || st[i].gender == "f") {
            femaleCount++;
        }

        if (maxScore <= st[i].score) {
            maxScore = st[i].score;
            maximum = st[i];
        }
        if (minAge >= st[i].birthday) {
            minAge = st[i].birthday;
            young = st[i];
        }
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "\t\t\tInfo Of Youngest Student " << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t________________________" << endl
         << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t\tName: " << young.name << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t\tID: " << young.id << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t\tBirthday: " << young.birthday << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t\tGender: " << young.gender << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t\tScore: " << young.score << endl
         << endl;

    cout << "\t\t\tStudent with Max Score: " << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t________________________" << endl
         << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t\tName: " << maximum.name << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t\tID: " << maximum.id << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t\tBirthday: " << maximum.birthday << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t\tGender: " << maximum.gender << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t\tScore: " << maximum.score << endl
         << endl;

    cout << "\t\t\tTotal Females in the class: " << femaleCount << endl
         << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to post a complete verifiable example and code that compiles.  You use commands like `cin` but did not include `<iostream>`  and for `string`.

Comment: Looks like someone else in your school course is working on the same assignment. This is a repeat of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68119751/) asked earlier today.

Comment: The youngest person has the lowest or highest birth year? If `minAge` contains a birth year should it initially be something very high or very low?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want to specify the year of birth of the student instead of their age. This obviously would not work since you are calculating the maximum by initializing the maximum age as `100`. For this to both work with year of birth and age, although it is semantically incorrect to use the same field `birthday` for both the cases, you have to start the loop by initializing all the values with the value of the first student. Then start the loop from `1` ,that is, from the second student:

```
int minAge = st[0].birthday;
int maxScore = st[0].score;
int femaleCount = st[0].gender == "F" || st[0].gender == "f" ? 1 : 0;
Student maximum = st[0];
Student young = st[0];
for (i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
    cout << endl
         << endl;

    if (st[i].gender == "F" || st[i].gender == "f") {
        femaleCount++;
    }

    if (maxScore <= st[i].score) {
        maxScore = st[i].score;
        maximum = st[i];
    }
    if (minAge >= st[i].birthday) {
        minAge = st[i].birthday;
        young = st[i];
    }
}
```

This would get the job done but I would strongly discourage against associating multiple meanings with a single field. Use either `age` or `year_of_birth` as the only field or define both while also defining a conversion function.

Comment: @AtiaFarzana You're welcome. If the answers helped, consider to encourage answerers of helpful answers by upvoting their answers and marking one of the answers as accepted by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You are asking the user to enter each student's birth year, but then you are comparing those values to an age expressed in years since birth. And worse, you are not accounting for the differences when the user enters a 1/2-digit year versus a 4-digit year.

IOW, you are comparing apples to oranges.  You need to normalize what input you are expecting, and how you process it.

If you want the user to enter a birth year, then require a valid year.  If the user enters a 1/2-digit year, adjust it into a 4-digit year.  Then, if needed, you can calculate the student's age by subtracting that year from the current year.

If you want the user to enter an age, then require a valid age, and then use it as-is.

Also, knowing that there are more than 1 student in the array can help you with determining the youngest age and highest score.  Rather than initializing `minAge` and `maxScore` to some arbitrary fixed values, you can instead initialize them to the values from the 1st student.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Student {
public:
    string name, gender;
    int id, birthdate, score;

    void readName()
    {
        getline(cin, name);
    }

    void readId()
    {
        cin >> id;
        cin.ignore();
    }

    void readBirthDate()
    {
        cin >> birthdate;
        cin.ignore();
        if (birthdate < 1000)
            birthdate += 2000;
    }

    int getAge() const { return 2021 - birthdate; }

    void readGender()
    {
        getline(cin, gender);
    }

    void readScore()
    {
        cin >> score;
        cin.ignore();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Student st[20];

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
        cout << "Student " << i + 1 << endl << endl;

        cout << "Enter Name : ";
        st[i].readName();

        cout << "Enter Id : ";
        st[i].readId();

        cout << "Enter Birth date (e.g. 2020) : ";
        st[i].readBirthDate();

        cout << "Enter Gender : ";
        st[i].readGender();

        cout << "Enter Score : ";
        st[i].readScore();

        cout << endl << endl;
    }

    int minDate = st[0].birthdate;
    //int minAge = st[0].getAge();
    int maxScore = st[0].score;
    int femaleCount = 0;
    int highest = 0, youngest = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
        cout << endl << endl;

        if (st[i].gender == "F" || st[i].gender == "f") {
            ++femaleCount;
        }

        if (st[i].score > maxScore) {
            maxScore = st[i].score;
            highest = i;
        }

        if (st[i].birthdate < minDate) {
            minDate = st[i].birthdate;
            youngest = i;
        }
        /*
        if (st[i].getAge() < minAge) {
            minAge = st[i].getAge();
            youngest = i;
        }
        */
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "\t\t\tInfo Of Youngest Student " << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t________________________" << endl << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t\tName: " << st[youngest].name << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t\tID: " << st[youngest].id << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t\tBirthday: " << st[youngest].birthday << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t\tGender: " << st[youngest].gender << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t\tScore: " << st[youngest].score << endl << endl;

    cout << "\t\t\tStudent with Highest Score: " << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t________________________" << endl << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t\tName: " << st[highest].name << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t\tID: " << st[highest].id << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t\tBirthday: " << st[highest].birthday << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t\tGender: " << st[highest].gender << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t\tScore: " << st[highest].score << endl << endl;

    cout << "\t\t\tTotal Females in the class: " << femaleCount << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If someone calls `getAge()` in 2022 or later, this will output an incorrect age. A better option would be to get the current year using date-time utilities.

Comment: @AmalK obviously, but I'm assuming that if the school is still covering the topic of basic input/output then it hasn't covered more advanced topics like date/time manipulation yet.